# Adding Google Ads Code in NextJS for Automatic Units

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm working on a nextjs project and I have to implement the google AdSense code that is for automatic ads.

So, my google ad code is just this:

```
<script
  async
  src={`https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADSENSE}`}
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
```

There is no specific ad unit code. Based on this script load, Google will automatically add the ads.

In such a case, how will I implement this in my NextJS project ensuring that the ads will continue to work with the route change?

Currently, the problem I see is that if I just place this in the `_document.js` head, the ads will load only on full reload. There are some tutorials describing how to implement google Adsense in NextJS, but they all describe the case when you have specific ad units created for Adsense, but not the case of automatic ads based on this script alone.

Will really appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Have you checked this https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/26/how-to-use-google-adsense-in-next-js

Comment: I've checked. As you can see it explains the implementation with reformating of specific ad units, not automatic ads.

Comment: Did you figure this out @asanas

Comment: No, right now, to make it work well I'm doing a force full-reload of each page. Till I get a proper solution.

Comment: @asanas That was my initial solution as well, but the problem with that is that it might be a violation of Google's placement policies.
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Auto-refreshing_ads

Comment: No, I'm not doing auto-refresh of ads. Only when a user clicks on a link to go to another page, instead of loading that new page in SPA mode, I load it as in the case of SSR.

Comment: Think I have seen a solution to this here https://ndpniraj.com/blogs/place-google-adsense-to-your-next-js-project.

Comment: nope not working i tried, but i found if you are on a free plan on vercel you cant use ads anyway.  So i guess i will quite here.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Using automatic ads with next js.

Answer (score 3):

When implementing Adsense for automatic ads into a Nextjs it's best to add the script tag in _app.tsx or _app.jsx

When using `<script></script>` it is to use Nextjs built-in tag for optimization. here is an implementation of automatic ads:

```js
//import Script tag
import Script from 'next/script'; 

//implementation 
<Script
  id="Absence-banner"
  async
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  onError={(e) => {
    console.error('Script failed to load', e);
  }}
  src={`https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADSENSE}`}
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
```

EDIT 12/8/23:
Due to the changes in Nextjs if you are using the `appDir` some of this may not work as intended.

To implement Adsense add it into your app you have to put it in the base `layout.tsx` or `layout.jsx` file.

You will still use the script tag but you will have to add it into the html using the normal `<head></head>` of the document.

```
import React from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script'; 

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
        <head> 
            <Script
                id="Absence-banner"
                async
                strategy="afterInteractive"
                onError={(e) => {
                    console.error('Script failed to load', e);
                }}
                src={`https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADSENSE}`}
                crossOrigin="anonymous"
            />
        </head>
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```