# React work with AdSense | Do they work together

Tags: reactjs, render, adsense

Does **React** work with AdSense in 2022?

I've one website where it does not pass the AdSense guidelines and I'm wondering whether it may be caused by react which loads all the content in a page like this (pretty react standard)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I do know that in the AdSense website they stated that it works better with a static content type, however all information is pretty vague and no where I've seen that you can't use react with AdSense, however nor the oppositve.

I think you can and I just thinking too much, especially because react is so popular, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use AdSense with React!

There is even some popular libs for react dedicated to ad sense, like

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adsense

If you worry about server side rendering then worst case this can also be done in React

Comment: ok @Damian Busz I've seen these packages. The thing is that the AdSense documentation gives your more questions that answers and gave me these doubts. Well ok.

Comment: Technically, just by using this npm package should work out of the box right?

Comment: @FedericoBaù seems like, yes. However if you feel like adding this without package then it should be also straight forward. 

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: not working with nextjs :-(

Comment: @mangrove108 you need to render ads as client side rendered component, not ssr - then it will work :-)

Comment: i am doing it that way i import them via dynamic import in nextjs but still not working, somehow it feels as if google made that intentionally to not work with react from facebook, it really sucks, i siffed through almost all resources but still i cant find one reliable example . . . i even gave a bounty of 50 points to another similar question from my own scores to get a solid example nothing so far. i think i wll remove these stupid ads. Time that somebody will build a adplattform themselfs.

Comment: @mangrove108 can u link me the question you posted? i will have a look. I have those running on nextjs with no problem

Comment: i didnt had a question it was from someone else. but i am looking how to implement i gave a bounty on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765027/adding-google-ads-code-in-nextjs-for-automatic-units

Comment: @mangrove108 I will have a look later today :-)